# Spritekit water flowing

Tags: objective-c, spritekit, xcode, fluid-dynamics

I'm wondering if there is a way in spritekit to implement water flowing through a path?

like this [water flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zom5Rwp7z7o)

Right now I'm generating the path using UIBezierPath and PaintCode

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: From the description of the linked video: "*During the last scene, one frame took 10 seconds to simulate and render.*" It sounds more like film vfx production than game development! Are you really sure [a simpler water model](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44547/7804) is insufficient?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by using `UIBezierPath`? Isn't that a rendering thing? I thought you were asking about the cool physics.

Comment: @Anko Thanks for your comments, After searching I found that I have to use liquidfun. Do you know how to implement liquid flooding using liquid fun and spritekit?

Comment: Wow, [Liquidfun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) does look fun. I've not used it, but looks like they have [a programmer's guide](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/Programmers-Guide/html/index.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very interesting topic.

You can build the water effect using SpriteKit and its integrated physics engine.

### Step 1

1. Create a Physics World
2. Create many little circular SKSpriteNode(s), each one will have a circular physics body matching the graphics representation

### Step 2

Then every frame you'll need to:

1. Draw all the sprites on a buffer
2. Apply a blur effect
3. Apply a threshold effect
4. Draw the buffer on the screen

You can get a better understanding of the process by playing with this interactive demo: http://www.patrickmatte.com/stuff/physicsLiquid/

Comment: what do you mean by Draw all the sprites on a buffer? Do you mean I have to save sprites in an array?

Comment: It's a technique used to draw on the screen objects after having applied some effects. In SpriteKit you can draw sprites on a  private buffer and apply effects on them using an SKEffectNode: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/

Comment: Sorry for bothering. But After I read the link you provide me I have a question: Do you mean by Drawing all the sprites on a buffer this? effectsNode.addChild(sprite) // the buffer is effectsNode which is SKEffectNode correct? Thanks again.

Comment: what do you mean by a threshold effect? do you mean: SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
sprite.texture, alphaThreshold: 0.9, size: sprite.size)?

Comment: Very useful link. Thanks again :) Can I take your opinion on this approach, http://www.tech.theplayhub.com/how_to_progressively_blur_a_skspritenodes_image_using_sprite_kit/ I think it bad do you agree with me? or do you recommended that I follow this approach?