# 2D sidescroller water surface shader

Tags: 2d, graphic-effects, side-scroller, water, waves

I am implementing a little 2d fishing side-scroller as a hobby. Here is a screenshot of the work-in-progress:

[image]

I have implemented a underwater distortion effect in a GLSL fragment shader, but I have troubles figuring out how to implement some sort of rolling waves on the water surface.

What would be a simple way to do this?

Comment: Hello, have you seen the existing questions like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44547/how-do-i-create-2d-water-with-dynamic-waves) ? This looks similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes it does looks very similar to what I had in mind! 
Hmm.. I did a search before posting but I didn't find anything. Thanks again!